# Programmatically close dialog opened by theme.dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have two xml files, and two java files. In the first xml I have few buttons, and one of them is EXIT. In the java file i write in the onCreate:

```
Button exitButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button_exit);
    exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then further down the code I write:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.button_exit:
        Intent switchtoExit = new Intent(StartActivity.this, ExitActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(switchtoExit, MESSAGE_REQUEST);
        break;
    }
}
```

the second java files is called ExitActivity.java. In the manifest file I wrote:

```
<activity android:name=".ExitActivity" 
            android:label="@string/exit_title"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
```

In order to make the second xml file popup like a dialog. 
My second java file is(the one that popup like a dialog):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ExitActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_exit);

        Button noExitButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.exit_no_button);
        noExitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button yesExitButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.exit_yes_button);
        yesExitButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.exit_no_button:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Choice :-D", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.exit_yes_button:
            Toast.makeText(this, "So sad... \nnice playing with you...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        //break;
        }
    }
}
```

and my second java file has:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@color/red">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/exitTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/exit_body" 
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/exit_no_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/exit_no_button" 
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/exit_yes_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/exit_yes_button" 
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I wanted to do is to have one button close the dialog, and the other button to stop the application. I tried finish(), and it worked just fine. but then when I added the onDestroy() method one button would restart the application, and the other just close it. Also, when I pressed the Back button, it would close the application.

Can anyone explain me how to get the following to happen:

1. When the dialog pops up, and I press the back button, it just closes the dialog?
2. When I press on exit button, it closes the application.
3. When I press on the Stay button it closes the dialog.

Thanks

Comment: Why did this question got -1?

Comment: Since your question is asking someone to code for you, instead you should ask specific, easy to figure out questions for SO members to answer. Noone has time to code for you.

Comment: I am/was not looking for someone to code for me. All I was looking for was a short sentence that describes the solution. I can find my way from there. Coding is an extra, and so are examples. But just sugessting a solution in words/pseudo is what I am looking for. Suggesting otherwise, maybe reflects on you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing this the wrong way.  Using a second activity is overkill.  Use an AlertDialog, which you can easily make with AlertDialogBuilder.  Set it to have a positive and a negative button.  Set an OnClickListener for the positive button that calls finish on the only activity.  There you go-  1 activity, and the dialog class itself will take care of popping up and closing itself.

Comment: But then, how do I close the application when the user presses the OK button?
I tried to add
 int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
   android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
but it just restarted the entire app without closing it.

Comment: Call finish().  That will close the current activity.

Comment: I am new to android programming. When I press the NO  exit button, I set finish() there, and it closes the dialog and returns to the first xml/java - that what I want to happen. But it does not close the entire application? I tried System.exit(0); and it will just restart the application.

Comment: OK, I found something that will have to do for now. I am using moveTaskToBack(true) for the second button, and that does the trick (at least visually). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what I did wrong that I got -1 on this question?